# How to handle tab changing in Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a page with some tabs. I want to fill a page item when I change tabs.
How can I do that?
Please tell me step by step, I'm so beginner in Oracle Apex

Comment: When you say tabs, do you mean changing selections from the Region Display Selector? Also, what version of APEX are you using?

Comment: Are you using https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ or something else?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/lease provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example